# Android Studio couldn't initialize class com.gradle.scan

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, android-room

I get this error when I try to run the app. I also get some Room database error but I fixed them,but this error occurs when I run the app.

Could not initialize class com.gradle.scan.agent.serialization.scan.a.g

```
* Exception is:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gradle.scan.agent.serialization.scan.a.g
at com.gradle.scan.plugin.internal.g.a.a(SourceFile:22)
at com.gradle.scan.plugin.internal.b.w.a.a(SourceFile:11)
at com.gradle.scan.plugin.internal.b.c.a(SourceFile:38)
at com.gradle.scan.plugin.internal.o.d.a(SourceFile:51)
at com.gradle.scan.plugin.internal.r.a.b(SourceFile:111)
at com.gradle.scan.plugin.internal.o.d.a(SourceFile:50)
at com.gradle.scan.plugin.internal.c.d$c.a(SourceFile:60)
```

Comment: Clean the project and rebuild. might help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not worked